# Why are social media links not working on OnePager

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a OnePager with 3 different wrappers. The menu is above the wrappers and applies to the whole page. But when I scroll down to the second and third wrapper, the social media links don't work anymore. The special thing is, as soon as I scroll to the bottom of the page, the github link works again.

- The page is on this github repository: https://github.com/Sari95/Portfolio-Sarah-Schuerch
- The menu with the social media links is in the file index.html

Does anyone have any idea why the links are not working?

Many thanks in advance, Sarah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your styles.css, you were having a z-index problem, the sections were in front of the icons. I also added something I think it would be nice, some padding to the links, so the clickable area is bigger

```
.left_menu {
  z-index: 100;
}

.social_icons_list a {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your hint. With the z-index it works.